# Android post request for datetime to SQL Server

Tags: java, android, sql, web-services, datetime

I have a web service to insert a new user to table users in SQL Server 2014. All the information gets inserted except the time, it is inserted as null.

Here is where I send data in Android

```
jsonBody.put("nickname",nickname.getText().toString().trim());
jsonBody.put("firstname", firstname);
jsonBody.put("lastname",lastname);
jsonBody.put("created on", Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault()));
jsonBody.put("phonenumber", phonenumber.getText().toString().trim());
```

All of them are sent correctly except for the time. By the way I defined the data type of the date as datetime in the SQL database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Needs more detail Adem.  What is your android client actually sending over the wire?  What is your web service receiving?  And what exactly is your web service trying to insert into the database.   I  would include you web service code (or a brief version of it)

Comment: We can’t tell from the information you have provided. It depends on what your particular web service expects for `created on`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the right answer.

Just replace

```
Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault()
```

with

```
  DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()).toString()
```

Comment: Your result will vary with the client’s locale and time zone, so there are probably many situations where it will not work. Better to use the server locale and time zone. Also you should avoid the `DateFormat` class. It is long outdated and notoriously troublesome. Better to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, and its `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`. Or ThreeTanABP, then the class is in `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter`.